# Horizontal swipe between two views

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I had a x uiview of(366 108)  and another uiview On the top of X Uiview with with (370,340) on the initial page loading of the view controller  the X Uiview will appear on the swipe of that uiview I need to hide the X uiview  and show Y uiview and Vice versa

Comment: show  your code what you tried

Comment: I am new to IOS . That's the requirement can you provide some reference

Comment: in here you can implement in multiple ways , if u did something we can get answer in easily

Comment: requirement for you or for someone else ?

Comment: The requirement is for me

Comment: You need to gives us more info about the scenario.Are you having two views side by side in your view controller?

Comment: I had a x uiview of(366 108)  and another uiview On the top of X Uiview with with (370,340) on the initial page loading of the view controller  the X Uiview will appear on the swipe of that uiview Ineed to hide the X uiview  and show Y uiview and Vice versa

Comment: please follow this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by couple of ways

1. Use a `UIScrollView` and add both views in scrollView horizontally stack, now set the `contentSize` of scrollView, also set `enablePaging = YES`
2. Or you can use `UIPageViewController` and add as many pages as you want and it will show one page at time. [Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) is tutorial which you can use for getting started
3. else use `swipeGesture` for directions left/right based on condition hide and show your UIView

Also read Apple docs for [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) and [UISCrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/)

Comment: the views are in vertical stack, this is not the suitable solution

Comment: You can do that as well, add views vertical stack way and set height of contentSize for scrollView, or in pageViewController you can just set orientation UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical

Comment: what's the bette solution

Comment: It depends, I will say if your views belong to two different ViewControllers use pageViewController else you can use UIScrollView